# The effect of removing pooling layers in the model's accuracy

Tags: cnn, accuracy, pooling

I know that removing `pooling layers` will lead to an increase in dimensionality and subsequently, make the training to be more time-consuming. But I'm wondering if it worth it to remove pooling layers or not? does it lead to a higher `accuracy`?

Have you ever seen any relevant papers, articles, etc. about this issue? (I've searched and couldn't find much things except for [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6806.pdf))

I even don't know how many pooling layers should I remove.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can pooling ever increase accuracy in convolutional neural networks?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/44518/can-pooling-ever-increase-accuracy-in-convolutional-neural-networks)

Comment: That couldn't answer my problem.